# Модальное окно при попытке обновить страницу

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

как вызвать Модальное окно при попытке user-а обновить страницу ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример:

**UPD.**

```html
<script>
    window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        // Для IE и Firefox 
        if (e) {
            e.returnValue = 'Sure?';
        }
        // Для Safari
        return 'Sure?';
    };
    </script>
```

Comment: я делаю просто тест для студентов, и вопросы тянуться с базы и пермешиваются, поэтому при обновление страницы должно быть предупреждение что тест будет закончен

Comment: Переделал, надеюсь, что подойдёт

Comment: спасибо, что постарался помочь) но вроде такое больше нельзя делать на современных браузерах